# Why a E2 VM instance is set for my Google Cloud set up?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine

For a bit of context, I'm an solo app developper, I use google cloud (Firebase) for my app back end. I have cloud functions running and because I need a static IP adress from some of them, I have set up a Cloud NAT, a VPC network and a static IP adress.

I started to noticed that I'm been charged for the use of a "E2 Instance Core running in EMEA"

But when I look at the dedicated VM tab in the Google Cloud console, no VM instance is listed.
I already contacted Google Cloud support that wasn't able to help me.

My questions are :

- Is it normal to have such VM with my set up ?
- If no, how do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to [`VPC serverless access connector`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc#create-connector) Google by default will reserve `e2-micro` machine types for the connector. The static IP for cloud functions requires VPC serverless access connector.